# Matlab rref() function precision error after 12th column of hilbert matrices

Tags: matlab, precision

My question may be a simple one but I could not think of a logical explanation for my question:

When I use

```
rref(hilb(8)), rref(hilb(9)), rref(hilb(10)), rref(hilb(11))
```

it gives me the result that I expected, a unit matrix.

However when it comes to the

```
rref(hilb(12))
```

it does not give a **nonsingular** matrix as expected. I used **Wolfram** and it gives the unit matrix for the same case so I am sure that it should have given a unit matrix. There may be a round off error or something like that but then 1/11 or 1/7 have also some troublesome decimals

so why does Matlab behave like this when it comes to 12?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It indeed seems like a precision error. This makes sense as the determinant of Hilbert matrix of order `n` tends to 0 as `n` tends to infinity ([see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_matrix)). However, you can use [rref with tol parameter](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rref.html):

```
[R,jb] = rref(A,tol)
```

and take `tol` to be very small to get more precise results. For example, `rref(hilb(12),1e-20)`
will give you identity matrix.

EDIT- more details regarding the role of the `tol` parameter.

The source code of `rref` is provided at the bottom of the answer. The `tol` is used when we search for a maximal element in absolute value in a certain part of a column, to find the pivot row.

```
% Find value and index of largest element in the remainder of column j.
[p,k] = max(abs(A(i:m,j))); k = k+i-1;
   if (p <= tol)
      % The column is negligible, zero it out.
      A(i:m,j) = zeros(m-i+1,1);
      j = j + 1;
```

If all the elements are smaller than `tol` in absolute value, the relevant part of the column is filled by zeros. This seems to be where the precision error for `rref(hilb(12))` occurs. By reducing the `tol` we avoid this issue in `rref(hilb(12),1e-20)`.

source code:

```
function [A,jb] = rref(A,tol)
%RREF   Reduced row echelon form.
%   R = RREF(A) produces the reduced row echelon form of A.
%
%   [R,jb] = RREF(A) also returns a vector, jb, so that:
%       r = length(jb) is this algorithm's idea of the rank of A,
%       x(jb) are the bound variables in a linear system, Ax = b,
%       A(:,jb) is a basis for the range of A,
%       R(1:r,jb) is the r-by-r identity matrix.
%
%   [R,jb] = RREF(A,TOL) uses the given tolerance in the rank tests.
%
%   Roundoff errors may cause this algorithm to compute a different
%   value for the rank than RANK, ORTH and NULL.
%
%   Class support for input A:
%      float: double, single
%
%   See also RANK, ORTH, NULL, QR, SVD.

%   Copyright 1984-2005 The MathWorks, Inc. 
%   $Revision: 5.9.4.3 $  $Date: 2006/01/18 21:58:54 $

[m,n] = size(A);

% Does it appear that elements of A are ratios of small integers?
[num, den] = rat(A);
rats = isequal(A,num./den);

% Compute the default tolerance if none was provided.
if (nargin < 2), tol = max(m,n)*eps(class(A))*norm(A,'inf'); end

% Loop over the entire matrix.
i = 1;
j = 1;
jb = [];
while (i <= m) && (j <= n)
   % Find value and index of largest element in the remainder of column j.
   [p,k] = max(abs(A(i:m,j))); k = k+i-1;
   if (p <= tol)
      % The column is negligible, zero it out.
      A(i:m,j) = zeros(m-i+1,1);
      j = j + 1;
   else
      % Remember column index
      jb = [jb j];
      % Swap i-th and k-th rows.
      A([i k],j:n) = A([k i],j:n);
      % Divide the pivot row by the pivot element.
      A(i,j:n) = A(i,j:n)/A(i,j);
      % Subtract multiples of the pivot row from all the other rows.
      for k = [1:i-1 i+1:m]
         A(k,j:n) = A(k,j:n) - A(k,j)*A(i,j:n);
      end
      i = i + 1;
      j = j + 1;
   end
end

% Return "rational" numbers if appropriate.
if rats
    [num,den] = rat(A);
    A=num./den;
end
```